# how to selects rows based on a single value against a comma separated column in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a table structure like below:
TestTable:

```
ID(number)|Names(clob)
1          'a','b','c','d'
2           'b','c','d'
3           'g','h','e'
```

Now I want to select rows in which Names column contains 'b',so the expected output will be the first 2 columns.
How can do it in Oracle.
Please remember, **the solution has to work in Oracle 10g as well as 11g.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the column Names really contain single quotes?

Comment: sorry , mybad, no it does not, just for understanding I have given, they are comma separated strings and the column is of clob type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `LIKE` operator:

```
select
    *
from your_table
where ',' || Names || ',' like '%,b,%';
```

Concatenated commas are to cover for the cases where b is present at the start or end of the string.

Comment: Previous one was correct,this one is returning 0 records!

Comment: @user2948533 - Updated the answer.

Comment: @user2948533 - if "the other version" (which we can see by reviewing the successive edits had `'%,''b'',%'` on the right-hand side) does not work, that means that you didn't tell the truth in the original message. Do your stored CLOBs really have single quotes around the letters, or not? Probably not, based on what you are reporting. So, please edit your original question and fix that.